# Windows 10 Enterprise Spotlight stopped working

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, cmd.exe, windows-spotlight

Here is what I have tried so far:

- Re-registered Spotlight App

  1. `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`
  2. `sfc /scannow`
  3. `powershell`
  4. `Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers |Where-Object {$_.InstallLocation -like “*SystemApps*”} | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml”}`
- Removed all spotlight background images from `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_<Package ID>\LocalState\Assets` folder and removed `roaming.lock` and `settings.dat` `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_<Package ID>\Settings`

Based on this [tutorial](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/windows-10-spotlight-not-working-fixed/).

None of these solutions worked. When I set my lock screen to background Windows spotlight preview shows an empty screen.

Does anyone have any other ideas on what should I try in order to get Windows Spotlight to work?

Answer (score 0):

You're running Windows 10 Enterprise. This is relevant because the Spotlight Group Policy settings only work on Enterprise and Education editions, so it's possible you have a policy set that disables it.

1. Run `rsop.msc`
2. Check the locations (policy paths) listed in this article: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/group-policies-for-enterprise-and-education-editions for any enabled policies that would disable Windows Spotlight, specifically:

   1. `User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Cloud Content > Configure Spotlight on lock screen`
   2. `User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Cloud Content > Turn off all Windows Spotlight features`
   3. `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Control Panel > Personalization > Do not display the lock screen`
   4. `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Search\Don't search the web or display web results`

Comment: Just checked `rsop.msc` there is no administrative templates section.